# Entlib Custom exception handler missing mappings

Tags: wcf, enterprise-library

I implemented custom exception handler which works, except mappings from xml configuration policy. Those mapping works with standard `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler`

My implementation

```
[ConfigurationElementType(typeof(CustomHandlerData))]
    public class IdentityFaultContractExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
    {
        public IdentityFaultContractExceptionHandler(NameValueCollection attributes)
        {
        }

        public IdentityFaultContractExceptionHandler(Type faultContractType, NameValueCollection attributes)
        {
        }

        public IdentityFaultContractExceptionHandler(Type faultContractType, string exceptionMessage, NameValueCollection attributes)
        {
        }

        public IdentityFaultContractExceptionHandler(IStringResolver exceptionMessageResolver, Type faultContractType, NameValueCollection attributes)
        {
        }

        public Exception HandleException(Exception exception, Guid handlingInstanceId)
        {
            return new Exception();
        }
```

and part of the configuration

```
<add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib" postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException">
          <exceptionHandlers>
            <add type="MyClass.IdentityFaultContractExceptionHandler, MyClass" exceptionMessage="An error occurred in the service." faultContractType="MyClass.UnexpectedServerFault, MyClass" name="Fault Contract Exception Handler" >
              <mappings>
                <add source="{Message}" name="Message" />
              </mappings>
            </add>
          </exceptionHandlers>
        </add>
```

When I remove `mappping` node service works, when I add, then I got error : unrecognize element `mappings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a CustomHandlerData attribute then your configuration needs to use XML Attributes which then get passed in as a `NameValueCollection` to the custom handler constructor.  If you want to have custom XML then you will have to use [Full Design-time Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664483(v=pandp.50).aspx#AddingFullDesignTimeIntegration).  If you want to go down that road then you should look at the [`FaultContractExceptionHandlerData`](http://ehab.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/Src/WCF/Configuration/FaultContractExceptionHandlerData.cs) source code since your code would probably be quite similar.